# Current child categories with category image

Tags: php, magento

I'd like to get the category image to the list of current child categories which I retrieve with the code below.

How I can do this?

```
<?php
$i=0;
$count=1;
echo '<div class="empty-row">';
$_categories = $this->getCurrentChildCategories();
foreach($_categories as $_category):
{
if($i %3 ==0)
  { ?>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="item <?php if($count > 6) echo 'nobg'; ?>">
            <h2><a href="<?php echo $_category->getURL() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?> &raquo;</a></h2>
        </div>
  <? }
  else
  { ?>
        <div class="item <?php if($count > 6) echo 'nobg'; ?>">
            <h2><a href="<?php echo $_category->getURL() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?> &raquo;</a></h2>
        </div> 
  <? }
  $i++;
}
$count++; endforeach;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the get child categories with image, if you want to get root categories as well, just modify the code.

```
<?php
   $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
   $_category   = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
   $_categories = $_category->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(array('url_key','name','image','all_children','is_anchor','description'))
      ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
      ->addIdFilter($_category->getChildren())
      ->setOrder('position', 'ASC')
      ->joinUrlRewrite();
?>
<?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
   <?php if($_category->getIsActive()): ?>
          <img src="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getImageUrl()) ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>" />
          <a href="<?php echo $_category->getURL() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?></a>
   <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```